# C++ Copy Constructor for the Structure containing enum

Tags: c++, enums, structure, copy-constructor

First of all, sorry about the noob question, as I have just started programming in C++.

I have a structure defined in a header file:

```
typedef struct DataStruct
{
    double foo;
    double foo1;

    DataStruct::DataStruct()
        : foo(0.0), foo1(0.0)
    {
    }

} DataStruct;
```

Then I have a function in another file which returns the object of this structure after populating it with values:

```
DataStruct SomeFile::SomeFunction(Foo foo)
{
    DataStruct dataStruct; 

    double foo2 = 5.8;
    DataStruct.foo = foo2;

    double foo3 = 6.0;
    DataStruct.foo1 = foo3;

    return DataStruct;
}
```

I am not sure if I have to create a copy constructor for this.  If I have to, I'm not really sure where I should create it and how.

Comment: Where's the enum?

Comment: Off topic: `typedef struct DataStruct { ... } DataStruct;` is a left-over from C. In C++ `struct DataStruct { ... };` is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to define a custom copy constructor for the example you have shown.  The compiler will provide a default copy constructor for you, which performs a member-by-member copy of the struct's values.  The default cop constructor is sufficient when the struct contains only trivial data types and/or types that define their own copy constructors.

It is only when you have to manage external resources (such as file handles, dynamically allocated memory, etc) when you really need to pay attention to copy constructors (see the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))).

That being said, if you wanted to define a custom copy constructor, it would look like this:

```
struct DataStruct
{
    double foo;
    double foo1;

    DataStruct()
        : foo(0.0), foo1(0.0)
    {
    }

    DataStruct(const DataStruct &src)
        : foo(src.foo), foo1(src.foo1)
    {
    }

    DataStruct& operator=(const DataStruct &rhs)
    {
        if (&rhs != this)
        {
            foo = src.foo;
            foo1 = src.foo1;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

That being said, given the example you have shown, the compiler may employ [Return Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) so `SomeFunction()` does not have to make a copy of the returned `dataStruct` variable in the first place (its `Foo` parameter is another matter).

Comment: Thank you so much for clarifying.